# How to load sprites manually from a file in unity?

Tags: unity, sprites, spritesheet

We're making a game, in which the User can apply their own textures to the game in order to make their own rooms. Is there a way to make a prefab with sprites, scripts, colliders, etc during runtime? With a script or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no. Prefabs are editor side only. By the way there is no need to make a prefab since you can build a generic GameObject and customize via script adding components and loading resources like sprites from file.

For Example

```
void Start(){
Sprite loadedSprite = Resources.Load("your_sprite_path", typeOf(Sprite));
GameObject go = new GameObject();

go.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
go.AddComponent<SpriteRender>();
go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = loadedSprite;
go.AddComponent<YourScript>();
...
}
```

Then if you need to store it you can save it to a file or inside a dataase.

Comment: Will that work the same way for a sprite sheet with multiple sprites on it, and how would we go about that?

Comment: Honestly I never tried it. If the textures you are going to load are also for animation purpose, things will get complicated, because [you can't change animation sprite at runtime](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/676812/unity-2d-can-you-change-a-2d-animation-clips-sprit.html). If you don't need to deal with animations, then, a nice load of code would be enough to dynamically load them, based on the fact that unity clips all the sprite in the sheet with a naming convention like "spritesheet_name 0", "spritesheet_name 1", ecc.